# How to push data from one page to another [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, client-server, websocket

I'm using sockets.io, express and php and I was wondering if it is possible to push something of a page (that only a specific user can see at the time) to another page other can see. For example, if an admin has:

```
<?php $a = $row['test']; //data from test table
$q = '<h2>'.$a.'</h2>';
$b = $row['options']; //data from answers table
$c = '<label"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="'.$b.'" onclick="">'.$a.'</label>
$output = ''.$a.','.$c.',<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">';
        echo $output
```

So this outputs as a question with radio buttons as options for the client to choose from. Is it possible for this to be pushed to the client. Like the admin will push first question and then the next, etc. I'm new to webscokets but I'm getting a hang of it but this is really cracking my brain. Any ideas will be really helpful.

**EDIT:**

At the moment, I'e gotten the normal user to be able to view the contents as set by the admin. Now, my problem is the admin controlling how the data is sent to the user/client. I have a button now that when a user presses next, the next data/question comes but I'd like for the admin to be able to control that. Like when the user submits the first data, the page loads and waits for the admin to push the next question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to implement this without Ajax.

Once the user's browser has displayed the page, it's going to stay static unless you change the content.

You *could* simply auto-refresh every few seconds, but a better approach would be to have the JS regularly poll the web server for new page content.

Comment: Really appreciate the help but I understand it a bit. Can you please give an example as I'm fairly new to websockets.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but as I understand you want to send some data after the page on client's browser is already loaded. This actually a quite a classic and common quesion on stack.

You cannnot add any data after the browser has rendered the page. To get more data user has to send a request, get or post. HTML forms requires you to refresh or redirect the from the page. therefore for dynamic pages you can use Ajax to send a ping to server at regular intervals asking for more data. Using Ajax you do not have to reload the page everytime.

You can also use websockets. Most modern browser support it. Websockets open a connection that remains open for the duration of the clients sessions. You can send data whenever you want without witing for user's request.

You can start here.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/websockets/index.htm

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2